# Barba.js : scrollRestoration and Wordpress issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, barbajs

I'm trying to put somme animation between my home and my single page using barba.js (if something works better with wordpress let me know), Actually when I click to my post, the single page is scrolled as the other page was, it restore the scroll even When I put

```
barba.hooks.before(() => {
  if (history.scrollRestoration) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
  }
});

barba.init({
  debug: true,
  transitions: [{
    name: 'projet-transition',
    from: {
      namespace: [
        'home'
      ]
    },
    to: {
      namespace: [
        'projet'
      ]
    },
    enter(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    leave(data) {
      console.log(data)
    },
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the scroll position when navigating through links, you can do this:

```
barba.hooks.enter(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

**About scrollRestoration**

`History.scrollRestoration` affects back and forward history navigation. If you need to restore scroll position when navigating backwards or forwards, check out [this barba.js github issue](https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/423#issuecomment-626875286). If not, I think it would be better if you don't set scrollRestoration to manual in the `before` hook, which runs on every page transition. You can place it outside barba hooks or in the `beforeOnce` hook.